# Renaming YouTube Livestreams

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to create this program in Java which automatically names a weekly livestream according to its date. However, I can't find how to remotely rename your YouTube livestream. I can start it via OBS, but I can't rename it. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [LiveStreams: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/update) to change the properties of the video you want to update.

> You can set values for these properties:
>
> - snippet.title
> - snippet.description

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot.

Comment: Great. Good luck with your development.